# Old de-linked content still appear on my site page

Tags: html, css, background-image

Hello I was trying update my entire site on a server by just deleting the entire project folder and uploading an updated one. I change my DB Connections and all. Whats funny is that the site working just fine but the bg images that have been de-linked from certain pages keep appearing. On localhost, the page show that the bg image has been change and new a one indeed has been used. But when I access the hosted site, old bg image still show and not the new one. The only thing that made sense to me was that this might be a cache problem. But after accessing the site from another PC, the same still happened. Old bg images are showing and not the new ones. How can I fix this?

here is my css rules:

```
#topper{
    background-image: url('../assets/wadajir/68163702.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom:2%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you have replaced all URLs? Or  is your picture's name the same as the old picture's name? Make sure that your url points to the new picture, and that it has a different name. (If the server has a file tree view, look into it as well, if things were really changed)

Comment: Alright, lemme check